# numpy 1-D array size reduction without losing the signature of the plot

Tags: python, numpy, contour, downsampling

In order to increase the computational speed, i need to resize the 1-D numpy array . The caveat here is that the numpy array is to be used as a shape descriptive curve which will further be utilized as a tool to classify the different class.

[image]

currently the array has 853 elements. The plot of the array is,

[image]

Is there any effective way to reduce the array size but i don't want the plot signature i.e charecteristics to degrade.
Note: i want to reduce 853 to 64 samples effectively without losing the content signature.

I used res=np.resize(srd,(64,)), to resize the 853 element srd array to 64 elements but the plot of the resized element is completely different. The plot of the array after resizing,

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code (not images). Minimum example will be useful.

Comment: res = np.resize(srd,(64,)), i used this code but the plot of the res array is completely different then the original srd array plot

Comment: Please post [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I also recommend [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With `np.resize` you are just keeping the first 64 elementes. You can see that in the plots.

Comment: Do you require the samples to be equispaced or do you want something more adaptive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resample a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085268/resample-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

1) Simplest solution would be taking every n-th sample of your signal (reduce the shape by a factor of n). Example:

```py
resampled_signal = signal[::2]
```

2) More advanced solutions involve using [resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) or [intep1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) from scipy library