# How do I scale down the python array?

Tags: python, arrays, plot, scale

I have an array of size 1000. I want to resize this array to 400 points.

I can't do truncation. Averaging is ok. Another way to this is to take every 2.5th element. But I can't do this 2.5 operation. How shall I appraoch this problem?

Comment: With numpy you can do non-integer array resampling as explained by [Resample a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085268/resample-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Is numpy a possibility? Or only pure Python?