# Calculate difference between two columns where row values are the same (difference between 2 functions)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume you have two DataFrames f1 and f2, with columns x, and y. We want to calculate an absolute difference between those two functions abs(y1-y2).

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 6), 'y': range(10, 0, -2)})
f2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 6), 'y': range(10, 5, -1)})
f_diff = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 6), 'y': abs(f1.y-f2.y)})

plt.style.use('default')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

axs.plot(f1.x, f1.y, color='orange')
axs.plot(f2.x, f2.y, color='red')
axs.plot(f_diff.x, f_diff.y, color='black')
```

[image]

Now, I would like to shift one of the functions to the left or right (apply vector transformation along X axis), and re-calcualte the absolute difference. See below:

[image]

So my question: How to calculate the difference between two columns (Ys) on locations where x values in two data frames are the same?
Obvioulsy we can't use a trivial abs(f1.y-f2.y) anymore. I was thinking about shifiting values in one of the y columns but I was wondering if there is more efficient solution.

Comment: You want to resample the data to the same x-coordinates, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085268/resample-a-numpy-array
But you'll have to think about what the difference is supposed to mean if the domain isn't the same for F1 and F2 as in the last plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
shift = 2
x_new = pd.concat([f1.x, pd.Series(list(range(last_x + 1, last_x + shift + 1)))]).reset_index(drop=True)
f1_y_new = pd.concat([f1.y, pd.Series([0] * shift)]).reset_index(drop=True)
f2_y_new = pd.concat([pd.Series([0] * shift), f2.y]).reset_index(drop=True)
f_diff = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_new, 'y': abs(f1_y_new-f2_y_new)})
```